# About Dynamic Form Design Generating

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-1.1

I'm working in a windows application. using VB.NET 1.1

I have an empty form, and I want to generate my design in load session (not in form_load event! but in my form's constructor)

So I know I must generate my components in constructor, but I don't know how to generate button events. I mean I haven't any button in design mode, and these are generating in run-time mode. so how I set button events in this session?

And if you have a better solution for run-time design generation, give it to me. thanks ;)

Comment: Another suggestion.  For each type of control that has common properties using a class that inherits the control and sets the properties you want might help make things more readable

Comment: @HighCore >> a good **ANSWER** is: our company's application is on .net1.1 platform. and I haven't permission to change company's application structure.... **SO** you should answer the question instead of ask a new question!

Comment: @HighCore .net1.1 is for visual studio 2003 , not 50 years ago! and I love my job, and don't want leave that. I say again my suggestion: please answer my question, if you can. and if you can't answer, please be silent.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. You may add controls at practically any point.  It can be in the constructor, the Load, in response to another event, or when a custom method is called.
2. You can wire up events by using `AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf Button_Click`.  You'll have to define the `Button_Click` event handlder and it will need to have the appropriate signature, which for a button click is `(sender as object, e as EventArgs)`.
3. When in doubt, temporarily add a real control to you form and go to the hidden designer code (`MyForm.vDesigner.vb`) and see what is generated as a sample.  Copy that code and move it into the main populating code.  Then delete the control.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, its early, not enough coffee yet